# Error in gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have written my code under button as follows

```
 string actkey = string.Empty;
    foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
    {
        //Label lbInvoice = (Label)row.FindControl("lblInvoice");
        string strInvoice = GridView1.DataKeys[row.RowIndex].Values["lblInvoice"].ToString();
        objinvoice.Invoice = strInvoice;
        RadioButton rdn = (RadioButton)row.FindControl("rdnRenew");
        if (rdn.Checked)
        {
            actkey = oCustomerDetails.CreateRandom(20);
            objinvoice.activationcode = actkey;
            objinvoice.editInvoice(actkey, strInvoice);
        }
    }
```

But i am getting an error at this

```
string strInvoice = GridView1.DataKeys[row.RowIndex].Values["lblInvoice"].ToString();
```

Is there anything wrong in what i have written

I declared my item template as follows

```
      <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblInvoice" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("invoceNo") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: Null reference exception was handled

Object reference not set to an object

Comment: So there's no element with the key `lblInvoice` in the collection.

Comment: I have declared as Item template please check i have modified my question

Comment: I have to declare the field name as in my database field right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the working one

```
 string strInvoice = GridView1.DataKeys[row.RowIndex].Values["invoceNo"].ToString();
```

and also for grid we have to assign Datakey values...

Answer (score 2):

```
<asp:Label ID="lblInvoice" runat="server" Text=<%# Eval("invoceNo") %>
```

You are getting this error because may be this line is not setting any value to `label`.

```
 string strInvoice = GridView1.DataKeys[row.RowIndex].Values["lblInvoice"].ToString();
```

if value is null then `remove(.ToString())` may be it will work

Comment: No no actually i called the wrong value in that instead of calling from  database field i called label field so i got an error

Answer (score 0):

Got the answer forgot to give `datakeynames` in `GridView`.